# Why does Word VBA tell me that a dialog box is open?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I'm trying to copy a selection to a new document and then export it to PDF, but I'm getting an error that I cannot resolve.

On the line `ActiveWindow.Close False` I'm being told

> **Run-time error '5479':**
>   You cannot close Microsoft Word because a dialog box is open. Click OK, switch to word and then close the dialog box.

Unless the export to PDF operation is firing up a dialog, I do not know what dialog would be open.

Can anyone please shed some light? Thanks.

```
'** Copy the selection *'
Selection.Copy

'** Create a new document to paste the copied text into *'
Documents.Add Template:="Normal", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0

'** Paste the copied text *'
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)

'** Change the location of the file open directory *'
ChangeFileOpenDirectory OpenDirectory

'** Export the document to PDF *'
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    OpenDirectory & "\ZENworks.pdf", ExportFormat:= _
    wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

'** Close the new document *'
ActiveWindow.Close False

CopyToNewDocument = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `ActiveDocument.Close` instead of `ActiveWindow.Close`.

Answer (score 0):

Especially when working with multiple files, it's a best practice to use object variables to represent the files, so that you have an easier handle on them and don't need to try and remember which is *Active* at any particular time, you can just refer to the object directly.

For your specific problem, make sure you are closing the *Document*, not the *Window*.

```
Sub foo()
Dim OpenDirectory As String
Dim tempDoc As Document

'Modify as needed...
OpenDirectory = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

Selection.Copy

'** Create a new document to paste the copied text into *'
Set tempDoc = Documents.Add(Template:="Normal", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

'** Paste the copied text *'
tempDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)

'** Change the location of the file open directory *'
ChangeFileOpenDirectory OpenDirectory

'** Export the document to PDF *'
tempDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    OpenDirectory & "\ZENworks.pdf", ExportFormat:= _
    wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

'** Close the new DOCUMENT *'
tempDoc.Close

CopyToNewDocument = True

End Sub
```

NB: it's usually recommended to avoid relying on `Activate` and `Select` methods (this explains it in detail). Of course this is not as possible to avoid the `Selection` in Word, but the broader point remains that avoiding it when possible will lead to better code that's easier to read and maintain in the future.